# How to set an Image in listTitle leading on the right side?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to set the image that is in the leading part on the right side

Can you please help me with this?

```
child: ListTile(
  leading: Align(
    alignment: Alignment.Right,
    child: new Image.asset(
      prod_pic,
   ),
),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is the `trailing` property:

```
ListTile(trailing: new Image.asset(prod_pic)),
```

Which, according to the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile/trailing.html), is:

> A widget to display after the title.
> Typically an Icon widget.

Comment: Happy to help! Don't forget to select the answer as correct

Comment: print("Done it ;) ")